# Team foundation Service Configuration in a workgroup

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm trying to configure TFS 2010,while I'm using VS2012.In Visual studio when I follow the steps below after entering the server name the form prompts me for a username and password or shows the error message cannot connect to remote server,but since I don't have any experiences configuring TFS I don't know how to find these information.

1. I go to eam explorer in VS
2. I connect to team projects
3. I write the server name which is for my colleague's system
4. Then I'm prompted for credentials or shows the error message cannot connect to remote server,So I can not continue...

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: So the TFS you are trying to access is hosted on your friend PC or yours? Have you tried http://hosseinioun:8080/tfs/web?

Comment: Thanks Matija,unfortunately again I receive the mentioned error!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.The account as not set correctly in the Team Foundation Administration console and after setting it correctly,I was able to create new team projects and other clients are now able to connect to this team project on my server.

Thanks